# Formatação de datas com calendar dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: java, formatação

Estou com problema em formatar a data para o formato dd/MM/yyyy

```
 Como aparece:                 Sat Feb 26 11:38:28 BRT 2015

 Como eu quero que apareça:    04-07-2015
```

***Aqui é como eu mostro na tela***

```java
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data de inicio: " + contato.getDataInicio().getTime());
```

***Como eu estou setando no meu Dao***

```java
 Calendar dataI = Calendar.getInstance();
                dataI.setTime(rs.getDate("dataInicio"));
                viagem.setDataInicio(dataI);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) do [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) utiliza o formato `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy` para retornar como um `String` o valor da data, em que:

- `dow` é o dia da semana, no seu caso `Sat`(sábado)
- `mon` é o mês, o `Feb`(fevereiro) do seu resultado
- `dd` é o dia do mês representado como dois dígitos, de **01** a **31**, no seu caso dia **26**
- `hh` é a hora do dia, com valores de **00** até **23**, o **11** da sua saída.
- `mm` é a representação, também em dois dígitos, do minuto, o **38** da sua saída
- `ss` é o segundo, novamente representado em dois dígitos, de **00** até **61**
- `zzz` é o *time zone*, o `BRT` da sua saída, podendo ser vazio, se não estiver disponível
- `yyyy` é o ano, em quatro dígitos, como o **2015**

Então, para a saída que você precisa, basta usar um [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) no padrão que você precisa, no caso, `dd-MM-yyyy`. Neste padrão, teremos:

- `dd` o dia do mês, variando de **01** a **31**
- `MM` o mês, não mais representado como `Jan`, `Feb`, etc., mas sim em dois dígitos, de **01** a **12**
- `yyyy` sendo o ano, em quatro dígitos

Um exemplo usando [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) seria este:

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Isto irá imprimir no padrão que você precisa.

Outro ponto que talvez seja importante observar: uma vez que [`getDate(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate-java.lang.String-) retorna um [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) e ela é subclasse de [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), não é necessário configurá-lo em um calendar, você pode fazer diretamente, assim:

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
final Date date = rs.getDate("dataInicio");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Para exibir corretamente na sua *dialog*, você pode usar algo desta forma:

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
final String dataFormatada = df.format(contato.getDataInicio().getTime());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data de inicio: " + dataFormatada);
```

Answer (score 6):

Quando executas

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data de inicio: " + contato.getDataInicio().getTime());
```

acontece uma chamada ao método Date.toString() para mostrar o conteúdo da tua variável. Por defeito esse é o output do método.

Podes no entanto usar a classe [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) para formatar o output da tua data do seguinte modo:

```
SimpleDateFormat format_ = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dataFormatada_ = format_.format(contato.getDataInicio().getTime());
//System.out.println(dataFormatada_);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data de inicio: " + dataFormatada_);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ;)