# Converter String para Date

Tags: java, string

Sou iniciante em java e estou com dúvida na conversão de String para Date. Já passei horas pesquisando na internet para ver se encontrava alguma solução e me deparei com pouquíssimas soluções mas quando ia colocar essas soluções para rodar, a minha aplicação sempre gerava erro!

```
 private boolean salvarPessoa(){
        pessoa.setNome(this.txtNome.getText());
        pessoa.setBairro(this.txtBairro.getText());
        pessoa.setEndereco(this.txtEndereco.getText());
        pessoa.setCidade(this.txtCidade.getText());
        pessoa.setUf(this.txtUF.getText());
        pessoa.setCPF(this.txtCPF.getText());
        pessoa.setTelefone(this.txtTelefone.getText());
        pessoa.setdNascimento(this.txtdNascimento.getText());// <- O erro esta aqui!
```

Comment: Eu acho que tem uma *trocentas* perguntas iguais a esta.

Comment: Qual o formato da string de data? E como disse o @bigown, o que mais tem aqui no SOpt são questões sobre formatação de datas, como [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72828/formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-datas-com-calendar-dd-mm-yyyy), [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83281/converter-string-com-data-para-datetime-em-java), etc. Basta tu ler a documentação e descobrir o formato que precisa.

Comment: Formato: dia,mês e ano. Eu já li mais não sei quase nada do vocabulário inglês e nem sei ler em inglês.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Crie um objeto de SimpleDateFormat inicializando o formato da data de acordo como está formatada a sua String, depois basta fazer um parse da String e jogar em um Date. Veja o código:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String data = "16/10/2015";
        try {
            Date date = formatter.parse(data);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Fri Oct 16 00:00:00 BRT 2015

Veja os [patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) para passar para o construtor do SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode passar a variável do tipo String como parâmetro para o formatter.parse e obter o resultado esperado como no exemplo :

```
@Test
public void testConversaoDataFormatoYY() throws ParseException {
    String exemplo = "10/16/15";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");  
    Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(exemplo); 
    //System.out.println(date);
    //Fri Oct 16 00:00:00 BRT 2015
}
```

ou com o formato YYYY :

```
@Test
public void testConversaoDataFormatoYYYY() throws ParseException {
    String exemplo = "10/16/2015";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(exemplo); 
    //System.out.println(date);
    //Fri Oct 16 00:00:00 BRT 2015
}
```