# Como eu faço para Scannear um dado do tipo Date?

Tags: java

Eu quero ler assim, porém não tem a opção que eu quero;

```
public class Cliente {

Date dataNascimento;

}

Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
cliente.setDataNascimento(e.next);
```

Fiz assim mas não deu:

```
System.out.println("Digite a Data");
String fechaComoTexto = e.nextLine();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(fechaComoTexto);
funcionario.setDataNascimento(date);
```

Comment: Não tem como ler um `Date` diretamente. Vc tem que ler uma string em algum formato (seja dd/mm/yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd, ou qualquer outro) e depois converter para `Date`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+converter+string+date

Comment: Fiz assim mas não dá  System.out.println("Digite a Data");
    String fechaComoTexto = e.nextLine();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = sdf.parse(fechaComoTexto);
    funcionario.setDataNascimento(date);
    System.out.println("Digite o Endereco");
    funcionario.setEndereco(e.next());
    System.out.println("Digite o Nome");
    funcionario.setNome(e.next());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível ler o objeto `Date` utilizando [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Somente `String`, `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal` e tipos primitivos.

Uma alternativa é receber a data como `String` e [converter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92787/77268) para `Date`.

**Exemplo:**

```
String data = "18/09/2019";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(data);
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Cliente {
    Date dataNascimento;
}

Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
cliente.setDataNascimento(e.next);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Assim daria certo

```
System.out.println("Digite a Data");
Date date = sdf.parse(sc.next());
funcionario.setDataNascimento(date);
```