# Erro na execução do metodo de busca do CRUD

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, crud

Estou fazendo um CRUD para um projeto da faculdade, porem estou obtendo esse erro ao executar os dois metodo de busca.

```
@Override
public List<ProdutoTO> select() throws SQLException{
    
    List<ProdutoTO> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Statement stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
    
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM T_GI_PRODUTO");
    
    while (rs.next()) {
        Long id = rs.getLong("ID_PRODUTO");
        String nome = rs.getString("NM_PRODUTO");
        Long quantidade = rs.getLong("NR_QUANTIDADE");
        LocalDate dtValidade = rs.getDate("DT_VALIDADE").toLocalDate();
        LocalDate dtFabricacao = rs.getDate("DT_FABRICACAO").toLocalDate();
        String categoria = rs.getString("DS_CATEGORIA");
        String fatorConvert = rs.getString("DS_UNIDADE_MEDIDA");
        
        produtos.add(new ProdutoTO(id, nome, quantidade, fatorConvert, dtFabricacao, dtValidade, categoria));
        
    }
    return produtos;
}
```

O trecho de codigo acima é o metodo para buscar todos dados do banco, quando executo ele retorna no console
[image: erro]

Esse erro aponta para os campos que tem data, sou bem novo em programação java e não estou conseguindo resolver, é o projeto final do semestre então não posso perguntar ao professor, ou melhor posso perguntar mas ele não vai falar.

Comment: Oi Israel, como está armazenada a data no banco de dados? É uma string (varchar), ou um formato de data? Isso pode ser um erro de conversão...

Comment: No banco está como varchar

Comment: Foi o que vc falou mesmo, como o dado estava gravado no banco, la estava como varchar e não como date, obrigado.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta com mais detalhes. Acho que pode te ajudar no teu projeto. Boa sorte aí

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para ler uma coluna e armazenar em uma variável em Java, o tipo deve corresponder. No teu caso, um VARCHAR deve ser convertido para Date (caso tu queiras manter o tipo da variável de data) ou tu deves trocar o tipo da variável para String.

Para converter a String para data, tu tens as seguintes opções:

1. [Converter para Date com um Formatter:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92785/converter-string-para-date)

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(<formato da data>);
    Date date = formatter.parse(<String com a data>);
```

2. [Usar LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746084/string-to-localdate) - isso permite localização para tradução e altaração referente à normas culturais (abreviações, formatação, etc)

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(<formato da data>);
    formatter = formatter.withLocale( <locale - identifica a localização> ); 
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(<String com a data>, formatter);
```

3. [Uzar ZonedDateTime](https://www.baeldung.com/java-format-zoned-datetime-string) - que contém informações sobre Timezone, horário de verão, etc. Nesse caso, pegamos o `LocalDate` anterior para gerar.

```
    ZonedDateTime startOfDay = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
```

Nesse código, a gente seta a hora para o início do dia e atribui a Timezone de Paris. [Aqui tem uma lista de timezones que tu podes colocar](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-display-all-zoneid-and-its-utc-offset/)