# Trasformar em formato "dd/MM/yy"

Tags: java, aplicação-web, java-ee, jsp

Estive fazendo o exercício "**6.4 Exercícios opcionais: Lista de contatos com scriptlet**" da Caelum e existe um questão que diz assim : "**2) Repare que a data apareceu de uma forma complicada de ler. Tente mostrá-la formatada utilizando a
classe SimpleDateFormat**"

Preciso por esse trecho:

```
String dataFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(contato.getDataNascimento())
```

Mas eu não sei onde coloca-lo já tentei substituir o **<%=contato.getDataNascimen....** , já tentei fora da table e nada..

Esse é o meu código!

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>E-mail</th>
<th>Endereço</th>
<th>Data de Nascimento</th>
</tr>
<%
ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();
List<Contato> contatos = dao.getLista();

for (Contato contato : contatos){
%>
<tr>
    <td><%=contato.getNome() %></td>
    <td><%=contato.getEmail() %></td>
    <td><%=contato.getEndereco() %></td>
    <td><%=contato.getDataNascimento().getTime() %></td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
</table>
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72828/formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-datas-com-calendar-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Já tentou assim: `<%=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(contato.getDataNascimento())%>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sou péssimo nessa linguagem mas acho que poderia fazer isso :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Endereço</th>
        <th>Data de Nascimento</th>
    </tr>
    <%
     ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();
     List<Contato> contatos = dao.getLista();
     for (Contato contato : contatos){
   %>
    <tr>
    <td><%=contato.getNome() %></td>
    <td><%=contato.getEmail() %></td>
    <td><%=contato.getEndereco() %></td>
       <%  
         String dataFormatada = new 
         SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(contato.getDataNascimento());%>
    <td><%= dataFormatada   %></td>
  </tr>
  <%
   }
  %>
 </table>
```

Anos que não mexo com isso ! =P